# Select last element using class name

Tags: jquery, css

This seems like it should be pretty simple - but I have not been able to figure it out.

```
<tr>
    <td class="data-command">1</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-text">2</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-text">3</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-numeric">4</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-date">4</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-numeric">4</td>
    <td class="data-command">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="data-column data-column-numeric">6</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-text">7</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-text">8</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-text">8</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-date">8</td>
    <td class="data-command">10</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to add padding to the first and last `<td>` in each `<tr>` with class data-column (so in the above example the columns with 2, 4, 6 and 9 would be selected).

At first, I tried using the `:last-of-type` and `:first-of-type` CSS selector:

```
.data-command:first-of-type { padding-right: 10px; }
.data-command:last-of-type { padding-left: 10px; }
```

However, this doesn't work because last-of-type cannot be used with a class.

Is there another way to accomplish this?  I tried using jQuery but I couldn't get anything to work...

## Update

There is a another piece of the puzzle that I left out.  So the type of padding that I add to the first and last column is dependent on another class in the .

If the last .data-column is a .data-column-text or .data-column-date, add padding-right, otherwise, don't add any padding.

If the first .data-column is a .data-column-numeric, add padding-left, otherwise, don't add anything.

Comment: Have you tried the jQuery .first() and .last() methods? https://api.jquery.com/first/ https://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: `.data-command` or `.data-column`? (text and code don't fit together...)

Answer (score 4):

Go through all `tr` using `each()` and find first and last `.data-column` in it and then apply `css` to them.

```js
$('tr').each(function () {
    var first = $('.data-column:first', this);
    var last = $('.data-column:last', this);

    first.css('padding-right', '10px');
    last.css('padding-left', '10px');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="data-command">1</td>
        <td class="data-column">2</td>
        <td class="data-column">3</td>
        <td class="data-column">4</td>
        <td class="data-command">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="data-column">6</td>
        <td class="data-column">7</td>
        <td class="data-column">8</td>
        <td class="data-column">9</td>
        <td class="data-command">10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:** updated `js` according to updated question.

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var first = $('.data-column:first', this);
    var last = $('.data-column:last', this);

    if (first.hasClass('data-column-text') || first.hasClass('data-column-date'))
        first.css('padding-right', '10px');
    if (last.hasClass('data-column-numeric'))
        last.css('padding-left', '10px');
})
```

Comment: Hey - this is great - there is actually one piece of the puzzle that I left out - the type of padding that I add is conditional upon whether another class exists in the first/last <td> - see my update above for more information -

Answer (score 4):

You can find `.data-column` in each `tr` and then use `:first` and `:last`  [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/861/)

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.data-column:first, .data-column:last').css('color', 'red')
})
```

Answer for **UPDATE**
In that case you can check class with `hasClass()`

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var first = $(this).find('.data-column:first');
  var last = $(this).find('.data-column:last')

  if (last.hasClass('data-column-text') || last.hasClass('data-column-date')) last.css('color', 'red');
  if (first.hasClass('data-column-numeric')) first.css('color', 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="data-command">1</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-text">2</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-text">3</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-numeric">4</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-date">4</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-numeric">4</td>
    <td class="data-command">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data-column data-column-numeric">6</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-text">7</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-text">8</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-text">8</td>
    <td class="data-column data-column-date">8</td>
    <td class="data-command">10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey - this is great - there is actually one piece of the puzzle that I left out - the type of padding that I add is conditional upon whether another class exists in the first/last <td> - see my update above for more information -