# CSS :last-of-type not working with multiple classes

Tags: html, css

I have the following html with CSS. 
http://jsfiddle.net/3zcwwjj5/4/

Table is dynamic so number of columns may differ.
How (with CSS) I can select last table cell with class *comment*.
My CSS is not working.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="comment">1</td>
  <td class="something">2</td>
  <td class="comment">3</td>
  <td class="comment">4</td>
  <td class="something">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="comment">1</td>
  <td class="something">2</td>
  <td class="comment">3</td>
  <td class="comment">4</td>
  <td class="something">5</td>
</tr>
</table>

.comment:first-of-type {
    background: red;
}

.comment:last-of-type {
    background: blue;
}

.something:first-of-type{
    background: yellow;
}

.something:last-of-type{
    background: magenta;
}
```

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307204/select-last-element-using-class-name/37307328#37307328

Comment: Is it possible to achieve what I want without jQuery? Only with CSS selectors?

Comment: use nth-child(num)

Comment: Not with css only - "comment" and "something" are of the same type - `td`. Needs javascript of some description to achieve.

Comment: Just as I wrote out my long explanation as to why it didn't work :-(

Comment: Thank you all for help, and pointing me in the right direction.